# Run function after a certain type of model is committed

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to run a function when instances of the `Post` model are committed.  I want to run it *any* time they are committed, so I'd rather not explicitly call the function everywhere.  How can I do this?

```
def notify_subscribers(post):
    """ send email to subscribers """
    ...

post = Post("Hello World", "This is my first blog entry.")
session.commit() # How to run notify_subscribers with post as argument
                 # as soon as post is committed successfully?

post.title = "Hello World!!1"
session.commit() # Run notify_subscribers once again.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No matter which option you chose below, SQLAlchemy comes with [a big warning about the `after_commit` event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.after_commit) (which is when both ways send the signal).

> The Session is not in an active transaction when the `after_commit()` event is invoked, and therefore **can not emit SQL**.

If your callback needs to query or commit to the database, it may have unexpected issues.  In this case, you could use a task queue such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) to execute this in a background thread (with a separate session).  This is probably the right way to go anyway, since sending emails takes a long time and you don't want your view to wait to return while it's happening.

---

Flask-SQLAlchemy [provides a signal](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/dev/signals/#models_committed) you can listen to that sends all the insert/update/delete ops. It needs to be enabled by setting `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = True` because tracking modifications is expensive and not needed in most cases.

Then listen for the signal:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import models_committed

def notify_subscribers(app, changes):
    new_posts = [target for target, op in changes if isinstance(target, Post) and op in ('insert', 'update')]
    # notify about the new and updated posts

models_committed.connect(notify_subscribers, app)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = True
```

---

You can also implement this yourself (mostly by copying the code from Flask-SQLAlchemy).  It's slightly tricky, because model changes occur on *flush*, not on *commit*, so you need to record all changes as flushes occur, then use them after the commit.

```
from sqlalchemy import event

class ModelChangeEvent(object):
    def __init__(self, session, *callbacks):
        self.model_changes = {}
        self.callbacks = callbacks

        event.listen(session, 'before_flush', self.record_ops)
        event.listen(session, 'before_commit', self.record_ops)
        event.listen(session, 'after_commit', self.after_commit)
        event.listen(session, 'after_rollback', self.after_rollback)

    def record_ops(self, session, flush_context=None, instances=None):
        for targets, operation in ((session.new, 'insert'), (session.dirty, 'update'), (session.deleted, 'delete')):
            for target in targets:
                state = inspect(target)
                key = state.identity_key if state.has_identity else id(target)
                self.model_changes[key] = (target, operation)

    def after_commit(self, session):
        if self._model_changes:
            changes = list(self.model_changes.values())

            for callback in self.callbacks:
                callback(changes=changes)

            self.model_changes.clear()

    def after_rollback(self, session):
        self.model_changes.clear()
```

```
def notify_subscribers(changes):
    new_posts = [target for target, op in changes if isinstance(target, Post) and op in ('insert', 'update')]
    # notify about new and updated posts

# pass all the callbacks (if you have more than notify_subscribers)
mce = ModelChangeEvent(db.session, notify_subscribers)
# or you can append more callbacks
mce.callbacks.append(my_other_callback)
```