# Perform celery task after successful commit in Flask?

Tags: flask, transactions, celery, race-condition

Relatively long-running task is delegated to celery workers, which are running separately, on another server.

However, results are added back to the relational database (table updated according to a `task_descr.id` as a key, see below), worker uses `ignore_result`.

Task requested from Flask application:

```
task = app.celery.send_task('tasks.mytask', [task_descr.id, attachments])
```

The problem is that tasks are requested while transaction is not yet closed on the Flask side. This causes race condition, because sometimes celery worker completes the task before the end of transaction in Flask app.

What is the proper way to send tasks after successful transaction only?

Or should the worker check `task_descr.id` availability before attempting conditional `UPDATE` and retry the task (this feels as too complex arrangement)?

Answer to [Run function after a certain type of model is committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378878/run-function-after-a-certain-type-of-model-is-committed) discusses similar situation, but here task sending is explicit, so no need to listen to the updates/inserts in some model.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is [Per-Request After-Request Callbacks](https://web.archive.org/web/20170426215411/http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/53/), thanks to Armin Ronacher:

```
from flask import g

def after_this_request(func):
    if not hasattr(g, 'call_after_request'):
        g.call_after_request = []
    g.call_after_request.append(func)
    return func


@app.after_request
def per_request_callbacks(response):
    for func in getattr(g, 'call_after_request', ()):
        response = func(response)
    return response
```

In my case the usage is in the form of a nested function:

```
    task_desc = ...
    attachments = ...
    #...
    @after_this_request
    def send_mytask(response):
        if response.status_code in {200, 302}:
            task = app.celery.send_task('tasks.mytask', [task_descr.id, attachments])
        return response
```

Not ideal, but works. My tasks are only for successfully served request, so I do not care of 500s or other error conditions.

Comment: Is this good to use flask g to handle this, and also how you are passing task_descr.id to this function send_mytask

Comment: Armin Ronacher is Flask's creator, so why this should not be production-ready? About g: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/api/#flask.g - this is the place to store request time data.

Comment: As for variables, they come from the outer function or method. Function `send_mytask` is a closure used purely for the `after_this_request` decorator.